# How to get django admin change form to pre-select choice field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model field with choices, as defined here:

```
class Pack(models.Model):
    SIZE_10x20 = Decimal(200.000)
    SIZE_10x10 = Decimal(100.000)
    SIZE_5x10 = Decimal(50.000)

    size_code_choices = (
        (SIZE_5x10, '5x10'),
        (SIZE_10x10, '10x10'),
        (SIZE_10x20, '10x20'),
    )
    size_code = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,
                                    decimal_places=3,
                                    choices=size_code_choices,
                                    default=SIZE_10x20)
```

My admin.py uses the default forms:

```
class PackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('size_code')
    fields = ('size_code')

admin.site.register(Pack, PackAdmin)
```

However, when I open up my admin panel and check the model instance change form the dropdown menu is not pre-set to the choice that is stored in the database. I've attached two images to demonstrate what I mean:

[List display for all model instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcq0m.png)

[Change Model Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0KYz.png)

It simply selects the one at the top of the list. I would like users to be able to make small changes to the model without always having to check and reset this field everytime this form is used.

I've looked into overriding ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data(request) but to no avail.

I have a similar choice selection on a Model CharField and do not have this issue with it. Is there something going on with the DecimalField that I am unaware of?

Comment: What version of Django are you using? And what backend are you using (SQLite, Postgres, MySQL)?

Comment: I am using version 2.1, and my backend is MySQL

Comment: Update: I ended up just going to float field instead of decimal field and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a form for your model, settings initial values:

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#initial

Then replace the form on your admin:

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I've been reluctant to make my own form because this model is still very much under development and team members are still often adding or modifying fields in the model. My understanding is that by relying on the default forms i'm quickly able to make changes to the model and have those changes be actionable in the admin panel.

Is it possible to build a kind of form where I can just add things to a 'fields' parameter like I currently do and have it automatically generate the form?

Comment: You just described django forms. Once you have the admin hooked up, any new field you add in your form will available on your admin. Is just as easy as adding a new field on your model class. Any tweak you may want do to on the `amin.py` itself you be a lot more complicated.